# Row Minimum except certain columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame below. I need to find the the row min and max except few column that are characters.

```
 df
  x y z
1 1 1 a
2 2 5 b
3 7 4 c
```

I need

```
  df
  x y z  Min  Max
1 1 1 a   1    1
2 2 5 b   2    5   
3 7 4 c   4    7
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Max = do.call(pmax, select_if(., is.numeric)),
        Min = do.call(pmin, select_if(., is.numeric)))

  x y z Max Min
1 1 1 a   1   1
2 2 5 b   5   2
3 7 4 c   7   4
```

Or a variation proposed be @G. Grothendieck:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(Min = pmin(!!!select_if(., is.numeric)), 
        Max = pmax(!!!select_if(., is.numeric)))
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** We can use `select_if`.  Here, we can use `select_if` to select the columns that are numeric, then with `pmin`, `pmax` get the rowwise `min` and `max` and bind it with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   select_if(is.numeric) %>%
   transmute(Min = reduce(., pmin, na.rm = TRUE),
           Max = reduce(., pmax, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .) 
#  x y z Min Max
#1 1 1 a   1   1
#2 2 5 b   2   5
#3 7 4 c   4   7
```

NOTE: Here, we use only a single expression of `select_if`

---

**2)** The same can be done in `base R` (no packages used)

```
i1 <- names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))
df['Min'] <- do.call(pmin, c(df[i1], na.rm = TRUE))
df['Max'] <- do.call(pmax, c(df[i1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Also, as stated in the comments, this is generalized option.  If it is only for two columns, just doing `pmin(x, y)` or `pmax(x,y)` is possible and that wouldn't check if the columns are `numeric` or not and it is not a general solution

NOTE: All of the solutions mentioned here are either answered first or from the comments with the OP

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 7L), y = c(1L, 5L, 4L), z = c("a", 
"b", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. But may I know what is reduce(., pmin) and bind_cols(df, .)  doing? I am confused with . symbol?

Comment: @DevP. It is more than one column, either we can specify `pmin(x, y)` `pmax(x, y)`, but that wouldn't be generalized as you may have lots of columns.  In `base R`, we use `do.call` and pass the function of interest.  In tidyverse, a similar option is `reduce`

Comment: @DevP. The `transmute` step returns only two columns that is 'Min' and 'Max'.  so if we need to create the columns in the oriiginial data, bind the original data with `bind_cols`

Comment: Thanks I see your an expert in R programming. May I know how you learnt? I know its by practice but we cannot remember all codes right?

Comment: Akrun, In case if we have NA in middle of the  rows?

Comment: @DevP. You can usse the `na.rm = TRUE` in `pmin/pmax`.  Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This one-liner uses no packages:

```
transform(df, min = pmin(x, y), max = pmax(x, y))
```

giving:

```
  x y z min max
1 1 1 a   1   1
2 2 5 b   2   5
3 7 4 c   4   7
```

**2)** If you have many columns and don't want to list them all or determine yourself which are numeric then this also uses no packages.

```
ix <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
transform(df, min = apply(df[ix], 1, min), max = apply(df[ix], 1, max))
```

If your actual data has NAs and if you want to ignore them when taking the min or max then min, max, pmin and pmax all take an optional `na.rm = TRUE` argument.

### Note

```
Lines <- "x y z
1 1 1 a
2 2 5 b
3 7 4 c"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution. Subset only the columns with numbers and then use `apply` in each row to get the minimum and maximum value with `range`.

```
cbind(df, t(apply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], 1, function(x)
    setNames(range(x, na.rm = TRUE), c("min", "max")))))
#  x y z min max
#1 1 1 a   1   1
#2 2 5 b   2   5
#3 7 4 c   4   7
```